# How to convert any type to a string

Tags: typescript

How can one convert any given type into a string?

I created the code below, but it isn't complete for many cases. As it is not trivial to solve this, I though before I reinvent the wheel, let me ask as perhaps someone has already invented this wheel

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (arg0: U) => void : never) extends (
  arg0: infer I,
) => void
  ? I
  : never

type LastOf<T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends any ? () => T : never> extends () => infer R
  ? R
  : never

type UnionToTuple<
  T,
  L = LastOf<T>,
  Res = [T] extends [never] ? [] : [...UnionToTuple<Exclude<T, L>>, L],
> = Res

type ConvertAnyTypeToAString<T> = T extends
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | bigint
  | undefined
  | null
  ? `${T}`
  : T extends symbol
  ? 'symbol'
  : T extends Function
  ? 'function'
  : T extends Date
  ? 'Date'
  : T extends Error
  ? 'Error'
  : T extends RegExp
  ? 'RegExp'
  : T extends Map<infer K, infer V>
  ? `Map<${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<K>},${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<V>}>`
  : T extends WeakMap<infer K, infer V>
  ? `WeakMap<${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<K>},${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<V>}>`
  : T extends Set<infer K>
  ? `Set<${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<K>}>`
  : T extends WeakSet<infer K>
  ? `WeakSet<${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<K>}>`
  : T extends Promise<infer K>
  ? `Promise<${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<K>}>`
  : T extends object
  ? ObjectToString<T>
  : 'not handled'

export type ObjectToString<
  T extends object,
  RemainingKeys extends (keyof any)[] = UnionToTuple<keyof T> extends (keyof any)[]
    ? UnionToTuple<keyof T>
    : never,
  Separator extends string = ',',
  Result extends string = '',
> = RemainingKeys extends [infer H extends keyof T, ...infer Rest extends (keyof any)[]]
  ? ObjectToString<
      T,
      Rest,
      Separator,
      '' extends Result
        ? `{${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<H>}:${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<T[H]>}`
        : `${Result}${Separator}${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<H>}:${ConvertAnyTypeToAString<T[H]>}`
    >
  : `${Result}}`

const sym1 = Symbol('hello')

type U1 = ObjectToString<{ a: 1; b: 2; c: 3; 1: 2, [sym1]:'A' }>
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFUB2BLA9ogKqgko00AnAZ2gGNQ1EAeeAPlgF5YAKeWaAD30QBMjYAhonCwA-CwEEA5gAYAXAgCUjegDdUyHrAWJoqwss7c+LYLEHT5sZIgBmhWNgA0wZQzUaeZsY+869hCAQMLAAMgJEoADytlQY9ExIlFi4+MRkFOhx7FzQvPxCIuLMbvQY2rC6+gT0RnkmJSrWdg4ASt7i7eb+1UFQcEnoWBgArpAANtBU3hgu5qGMYRHRsfFzsK3Q-EwA2hgAujnG-DtVhIfiO4cKOwB094OYqKMTUwCiHKTjIzxTs2G0WhOML7FwJDZbPohADC6GqoAAgsIMP0sAiAMqgAg2KRxcHlOr5bwAH1gkWxiCkJMqIwAtgAjQLmUn01CoSZCan05BSGygakjXjQWw2aBeZk08bjDqwAAGABIAN4YAC+sr8sAJuXyZPADPZMoA5EQ9azxoaNVrjrAAGKC8iUI22e2ZRAW7qao71fgAEQE+CNfvw7oqVu9sDeBAIqAIRsj0YIIYUYZ1mykH0gRrTGaTnsJJgAsgJIFQbPYCLAANLAssOABqtBlsqLJaVsMQ8KR4BRMDRmIpuMrtBVTjbcMIiORqNQGKxOKoDZVtHVHpTJgA6tABABrFulloV6vNcuwBtNzc7vdjjsTrs96B9ueUqhDkfXztT3sz-vzxfLy1ejq6LQKA+4nkOTbAaB763p+D7fk+g7Dv+q6ARuW7blBYEOBB5jiLKF6YSBVAwQQk7dtOs4Di+yErqGaH8AACtGtLICQ2GHo2eFysxqCsexpHkfej7Ua+KH0fm-CoPSABWGQylEskZFgP7PvEGqGogqCgLAAAWQg8JMPAWsAnCQDGOnBHAilyeQKmIdM5hrlJSnkOsmy0gINg4pW0DgPwkksNufmoLYgjCIoVyLI8wxjJMVDBeAoWarU2oNIlyWFJF+zeNxMXPHFUwZWF6nmB6ZwEOswGQJI-oxgxZKIYshpOC13ibEQIzjDpgXkjizVteCHleSglK+f5DU7LWFYABINcVmrAvctzTRCkQNcwC1ZVcOXcTZymoKpuK5WVswneYHWgOsZWwNVtWgDG11lYahoNR1XX8jdN34Yqgl3pRR1UDNw5yH9cEifOGA7DN+zDnRX0VAqirvd1KpKndBB1QQaOKu2H4UV+VHzsDKqg7j45kf9hOA1DMNwydXGI0qKOgCqaogKQ6DrSatIAIyLOiprsswhq6dAUqoIaihQgM-NMPtdmHQ5iqCAovMANywPSCgAEya6QCgAMya7zuvAjsPO8-sciGgir1LsAQA)

Comment: Um... how many things do you want to handle? What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: All possible types.  The current code needs a lot of work to properly display all types, for example it returns 'Function' as the string, whereas it would be better if it transformed it into e.g. `(arg: string)=>void`.  The same applies to may of other the types.

Comment: Are you asking for external libraries?  There is no canonical way to do this in TypeScript; there was an intrinsic `TypeToString<T>` in [ms/TS#40468](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40468) but it was never merged.  Also... what's the use case?  I don't see why you want to turn a type into a string literal type; how would you use it?

Comment: @jcalz: I'm creating a Zod clone, and each type returns a type string that can be queried.  I.e. one can do `console.log(myType.type)` and it would print out the equivalent of the typescript type.

Comment: How does `myType.type` exist at runtime? Your code above just makes a string literal *type*, not the string itself.  Maybe you want to use the [TypeScript compiler API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) and use `typeToString()` there, if you're looking for an actual string at runtime somewhere.  I'm afraid I'm still not understanding the use case.

Comment: At runtime I create the string and that's relatively simple as JavaScript enables easy conversion of types into strings.  However I want `myType.type` to be correctly typed by the Typescript compiler - i.e. to show e.g. `(arg: string)=>void` and not just show simply `string`, hence the need to convert every type into a string.

Comment: "JavaScript enables easy conversion of types into strings" ?? TypeScript types are erased before the code is emitted to JavaScript.  It really feels like you should be using the compiler API, but I guess I'm not likely to understand what you're doing and additional comments from me are just cluttering things so I'll disengage now.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz, sorry for any unclear responses from me. The user creates the type e.g. `const x = z.object({a: z.string()})`  I can trivially convert that into `{ a: string }` at runtime.  I've type things so that the compiler also knows the typing is  `{ a: string }`. Now all that's required is to convert that to a more useful string - so that `x.type` is reflected as `{a: string}` not `string`.

Comment: The details of what the string should look like are completely dependent on how you implement that zodlike-schema-to-string code, so we would need to see it (or a scaled-down [mre] of it) in order to proceed. And even with that it could be impossible given that union and keyset orderings are not guaranteed to be stable; imagine all the trouble you go through and end up with a runtime string `"Date | {a: number, b: boolean}"` but the compile time string `"{b: boolean, a: number} | Date"`.  At that point `string` is an improvement.

Comment: Personally I'd suggest just using a [branded type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) like `type TypeToString<T> = string & {__type: T}` and then have `x.type` be `"{a: string, b: number}"` or `"{b: number, a: string}"`
 or whatever at runtime, but `TypeToString<{a: string; b: number}>` at compile time, and you don't need to worry about the correspondence between your string producing function and string literal types.  ... anyway, I think I'd better stop corresponding for real.

Comment: That's right.  My requirement is however simple: some way to convert the type as know by the typescript compiler into a string - i.e. the very same string that it shows in VS Code.  Ideally something like `ToString<T>` - and the string returned is the same string as VS Code sees.  So the order should be identical to the way typescript currently determines it.

Comment: Why would having the type as a string be useful?

Comment: @vr. it's primarily to be more helpful to the developer.  Instead of the type of the variable being  `{ type: string, ... }`, I can return `{ type: '{ a: number }', ... }`  as I know at compile time what the actual string will be.